# Ubunt 14.04 freezes from time to time

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I have a GTX 980M nvidia with  4.2.0-22-generic. My screen freezes from time to time. I have disabled the touch pad with

synclient TouchpadOff=1 in ~/.config/autostart.

How do I debug this? I have to reboot, nothing else work. REISUB, ctrl+alt+f7 nothing works.

Comment: You mention the touch pad. Do you think it's part of the problem? If so, how and why?

Comment: I just tried eliminating the touch pad issue. I don't know if its something else. But when the problem happens there is nothing I can do . Just looking for some tricks on how to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you describe seems to derive from a not properly working NVIDIA graphics card. Generally you should use the drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories. When you encounter problems with these drivers - you can install the more current drivers from the GPU Drivers PPA. This often leads to properly working graphics, especially on very new NVIDIA GEFORCE adapters.

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers for GTX 980M.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Looks like that fixed it. Went one day without a reboot.